# Получить уникальные записи из БД по дате создания

Tags: mysql, sql

Таблица MYSQL

[image]

Нужно получить список товаров (без повторов goodId) и поле discount, отсортированный по createdAt.

То есть такой вывод:

[image]

Такое решение выведет goodId и createdAt, но не знаю как добавить поле discount

```
SELECT goodId, MAX( createdAt ) AS maxcreated
FROM test
GROUP BY goodId
ORDER BY maxcreated DESC
```

Comment: Укажите ТОЧНУЮ версию MySQL. Хотя в любом случае задача стандартная - выбор первой записи в группе.

Comment: Версия MySQL 8.0.30

Comment: тогда читать про `row_number()`

Comment: Вообще не проблема. ROW_NUMBER() в CTE и WHERE rn=1 во внешнем запросе.

Comment: Акина, @teran спасибо за ответы, уже пошел читать, но вы бы сэкономили мне много времени если бы написали пример в рамках заданной таблицы

Comment: Если мы приведем тебе пример в рамках данной таблицы, ты просто скопируешь его и на этом все закончится. Если же ты пойдешь почитаешь доки и применишь их на практике, то получишь кое какой опыт, и в последующие разы, уже можешь решить подобное самостоятельно. Возможно даже, ты заодно почитаешь и сопутствующие темы с другими функциями, например

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Благодаря комментариям @Akina и @teran я узнал про ROW_NUMBER и написал такое решение:

```
WITH parts AS 
(
  SELECT goodId, discount, createdAt, 
  ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY goodId ORDER BY createdAt DESC) AS row_num
  FROM test
)
SELECT * FROM parts WHERE row_num=1;
```

Надеюсь это поможет кому-то с похожей задачей :)

Comment: Вот и славненько..

Answer (score 0):

Предлагаю рассмотреть вариант если точно следовать поставленной задаче:
Конечно вместо строки **MAX(discount)  AS discount** можно использовать все что надо.
Например **AVG(discount)** или **MIN(discount)**

```
SELECT  goodId, 
        MAX(id), 
        MAX(discount)  AS discount, 
        MAX(createdAt) AS createdAt 
        FROM test 
        GROUP BY goodID
        ORDER BY createdAt
```